# some problems when Loading model and prediction

Tags: python, shell, speech

I am reproducing the experiment of the paper：SEGAN: Speech Enhancement Generative Adversarial Network，The author posted the code and the trained model on github：https://github.com/santi-pdp/segan.However,there are few information about how to load the trained model.
I have downloaded the model,[image]

in picture 1, segan_v1.1  is the trained model parameter provided by the author,I created the folder test_wav,test_wav is the test data I downloaded (provided by the author in the article),the clean_wav.sh is the test script.
Figure 3 is the original test script,Figure 4 is the script I modified based on the test data path I downloaded.The following error occurred when I ran the sh script under ubuntu18.04:
[image]
I am not sure if there is a problem with my data path, please help me to solve it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: post code as **text** please

Comment: Update the link to be: https://github.com/santi-pdp/segan

Comment: Try to download these three modules `numpy==1.12.1`
    `scipy==0.18.1`
    `tensorflow_gpu==0.12.1`

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237865/how-does-a-shell-script-read-the-data-in-a-batch-test-folder