# How does a shell script read the data in a batch test folder

Tags: shell, tensorflow, speech

I recently replicated a SEGAN experiment based on TensorFlow0.12.1.The author provides a shell script for testing (clean_wav.sh), as shown in the figure below:

[image]

This is the original version provided by the author. According to the path of my test data, the modified version is as follows:

[image]

Noisy_testset_wav_16k is my test data folder, but running the script system will report an error:

[image]

This folder is a directory, but when I change the path to:

```
NOISY_WAVNAME='/home/zyf/SEGAN/ SEGAN/segan-master1/noisy_testset_wav_16k/p232_023.wav'
```

the script runs normally and the program function can also be achieved.

However, only one audio file can be processed at a time and cannot be processed in batches.Hope everybody knows reason or have opinion, can give me give advice or two, thank very much.

Comment: please take a look at the [tour] page and post a [mcve]. You should post your code, so people can test it. Nobody will copy the code from a screenshot doing the job neither you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is written in the way it only processes file, you can add a loop in shell script to process all files in the folder:

```
for f in $NOISY_WAVDIR/*.wav; do
      python main.py --init_noise_std 0. --save_path segan_v1.1 \
               --batch_size 100 --g_nl prelu --weights SEGAN-41700 \
               --preemph 0.95 --bias_deconv True \
               --bias_downconv True --bias_D_conv True \
               --test_wav $f --save_clean_path $SAVE_PATH
done
```

but that would not be optimal use of the GPU since you do not process audio in batch. Ideally you'd want to modify python code to process audio in batches but that would not be a trivial task.

Comment: I have tried it ,but it did't work.I'm not sure if the author programmed the program to process only one voice file at a time, or if I missed something.

Comment: The author wrote the program to process single file at a time, yes

Comment: I found a solution on another website，now i can  process multiple voice files